# What is the dimension of the vector space consisting of all 3 by 3 symmetric matrices? What is a basis for it?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

Could you please explain the following and give me a meticulous solution:"What is the dimension of the vector space consisting of all 3 by 3 symmetric matrices? What is a basis for it?"
Solution till now:

Let Matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\h&i&j\end{pmatrix}$$

Since it's symmetric  $c=h$, $d=b$, $f=i$

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\b&e&i\\c&i&j\end{pmatrix}$$

$A$ could be written as $$A=a \times\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} +b\times\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+c\times\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}+e\times\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+i\times\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}+j\times\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

What's the conclusion?
Is it six dimentional matrix?

Comment: Look at matrices that only have a non-zero entry equal to $1$ in a position and its symmetric with respect to the diagonal. There are $3$ of them, when you put the $1$ in the diagonal, and $\frac{(3-1)3}{2}$, when you put the $1$'s outside the diagonal.

Comment: What will their diagonal and non-diagonal entries look like?

Comment: So you've shown now that in order to make **any** symmetric matrix, you just need 6 matrices. Can you do it with fewer?

Comment: I think not,with my knowledge that's how it seems.

Comment: I agree, so now you know that you need exactly $6$ generators, and it's not possible with fewer. Now, from your previous post you know that the set of symmetric matrices forms a vector space. Can you see what the basis of your vector space is (if you consider the matrices to be vectors), and also what the dimension is?

Comment: So they key was to interpret matrices as vectors,if i do so its dimension is six.

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Any symmetric matrix $\mathbf{A}\in M_{3,3}(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as

> $$\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\b&d&e\\c&e&f\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you write $\mathbf{A}$ as a sum of some matrices multiplied by some scalars?

---

You have found that any symmetric matrix may be written $$A=a\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} +b\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}+e\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+i\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}+j\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$ The trick is to realize that the set of all symmetric matrices forms a vector space, and that you may consider each of the $6$ matrices as vectors. To emphasize this, $(1)$ may be written as $$A=aM_1+bM_2+cM_3+eM_4+iM_5+jM_6$$ Next thing is to note that $M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4,M_5,M_6$ are all linearly independent, because the only way to have $A$ be the zero-matrix is precisely when $a=b=c=e=i=j=0$. It therefore follows that $\{M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4,M_5,M_6\}$ is a basis for your vector space, and the dimension is $6$.

Comment: Yes ,i've managed that much.I wrote the matrix as a sum of six other matrices but i don't know what to conclude from that.

Comment: Then you should edit your question and include that, that way we know that you have made an effort. You should write down the six matrices in your question, I'm sure you're close to solving it.

Comment: Edit your question, upload a picture of your work (if that is easier) and I'll help you format it.