# Find the kernel and nullity of $T: M_{3\times 3} \rightarrow M_{3\times 3}$ with $T(A) = A - A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to find the kernel, a basis for the kernel, and nullity of the vector space $T$:

> $T: M_{3\times 3} \rightarrow M_{3\times 3}$ with $T(A) = A - A^T$

I understand the kernel is:

$$\ker T = \{A : A = A^T, A \in M_{3\times 3}\}$$

So a basis for $\ker T$ would be a basis for all 3x3 symmetric matrices.

From here: [What is the dimension of the vector space consisting of all 3 by 3 symmetric matrices? What is a basis for it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813446/what-is-the-dimension-of-the-vector-space-consisting-of-all-3-by-3-symmetric-mat)

I know that the dimension of the basis for $\ker T$ would be 6, thus $\mathrm{nullity}(T) = 6$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your proof is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

- Clearly, $\newcommand{\t}{\mathsf{T}} A \in \ker(T) \iff A - A^\t = 0 \iff A = A^\t$ hence $\ker(T)$ is precisely the symmetric $3 \times 3$ (presumably real) matrices. (For simplicity I'll denote this space by $\mathrm{Sym}_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)$.)
- Clearly, a basis for $\mathrm{Sym}_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)$ is given by
  $$\left\{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$
  Hence, $\mathrm{Sym}_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)$ is $6$-dimensional over $\Bbb R$, and so is $\ker(T)$ as a result.
- Consequently $\mathrm{nullity}(T) = \dim_{\mathbb{R}}(\ker(T)) = 6$,